# How to get firestore data

Tags: java, android

I tried to get the data from firebase but I'm not able to add it in a model

```
private void getListItems() {
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    db.collection("users").document(user.getUid()).collection("coins").get()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                       Log.d("Data", queryDocumentSnapshots);
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Note that `onSuccess` is not called when the query fails. Could you try the `addOnCompleteListener` as shown in the docs instead? https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#java_8

Comment: are you able to get the data?

Comment: Got the type of data I want by iterating `for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                    Log.d("Data", document);
                        }`